# How to trigger C-preprocessor error about undefined symbol at #if? (LLVM/CLang/Xcode)

Tags: c-preprocessor

How to trigger C-preprocessor error about missing definition at #if?
I'm using LLVM/Clang/Xcode.

This code works.

```
#define AAAAA 1
#if AAAAA
#endif
```

And I expected this code will be an error for undefined symbol.

```
//#define AAAAA 1     Removed definition.
#if AAAAA
#endif
```

But it did not. Is this standard/regular behavior? And is there other way to triggering preprocessor error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let the compiler check this for you, without rewriting your code, you can use the `-Wundef` switch as documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html).

In your Xcode project under TARGETS / YourTarget / Build Settings, add `-Wundef` to "Other Warning Flags" (aka. `WARNING_CFLAGS`).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to raise an error if a particular symbol is not defined.  If so then just use the `#error` preprocessor directive

```
#ifndef AAAAA
#error Some Message
#endif
```

Comment: There's a typo in the example code.  The correct syntax is `#ifndef AAAAA` or `#if !defined(AAAAA)`

Comment: Thanks! This is what I've been looking for!