# Preprocessor equality test, is this standard?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I had envisaged one of these in the project preferences

- `TESTING` = `HOST`
- `TESTING` = `TARGET`
- `TESTING` not defined at all

My problem is with the latter.

It seems that instead of

```
#if TESTING==HOST
#error "HOST defined"  // add temporarilly for testing porpoises
#endif
```

I need to code

```
#ifdef TESTING   
#if TESTING==HOST
#error "HOST defined"  // add temporarilly for testing porpoises
#endif
#endif
```

I am convinced that this is not-standard behaviour, since if `TESTING` is not defined then it certainly doesn't equal `HOST`, and I do not need that extra `#ifdef TESTING` with the GCC compiler.

However, when I use the Atmel AVR Studio (which I *think* is based on MS Visual Studio), it is necessary to add that initial `#ifdef TESTING` in a few dozen places :-(

It looks like I have no choice, but I just wondered if any C standard acually requires this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
#if TESTING==HOST
```

If `TESTING` is not defined, then

it is equivalent to:

```
#if 0==HOST
```

From the C Standard:

> (C99, 6.10.1p4) "After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords)         are replaced with the pp-number 0""

Comment: In that case, if @Mawg defines `HOST` as `1` and `TARGET` as `2`, then his original test of `#if TESTING == HOST` should fail if `TESTING` is undefined, correct?

Comment: +1 @ouah  So, if neither TESTING nor HOST are defined then the condition is true?  That explains it. Thanks

Comment: As described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852507/how-to-trigger-c-preprocessor-error-about-undefined-symbol-at-if-llvm-clang-x -- some compilers can report a warning in case of use of undefined macro expansion with the `-Wundef` option.

Comment: The quote from the standard refers to #if directives only, not to macro replacements in general.

Answer (score 12):

And note that you can do this:

```
#ifndef TESTING
    ...
#elif TESTING == HOST
    ...
#elif TESTING == TARGET
    ...
#else
    #error "Unexpected value of TESTING."
#endif
```

Also:

```
#if defined(TESTING) && TESTING == HOST
    ...
#endif
```

If you want to collapse the tests.  The parenthesis are optional (`#if defined TESTING` is valid) but I think it's clearer to include them, especially when you start adding additional logic.

Answer (score 3):

The original C preprocessors required explicit `#ifdef` validation before using a symbol.  It is a relatively recent innovation (perhaps driven by scripting languages like Javascript) to assume that undefined symbols have a default value.

Why don't you always insure the symbol is defined?:

```
#ifndef TESTING
 #define TESTING  (default value)
#endif

#if TESTING==HOST
  ...
#elif TESTING==TARGET
 ...
#else
 ...
#endif
```

Alternative, maybe force a selection?:

```
#ifndef TESTING
 #error You must define a value for TESTING
#endif
```

Comment: How do you classify C89?  Relatively recent, or ancient?  The C preprocessor behaviour was standardized back then, and its handling of undefined symbols in conditional tests was the same in 1989 as in 1999 and 2011.

Comment: I think that practice is merely a convention and never a requirement.  It allows an alternate definition to be provided on the compiler command line (or preceding include file) that overrides that defined in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It used to be the compiler would error if the #if parameter was not defined which is what I wanted.  I learned the hard way this is no longer the case.  The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
#define BUILDOPT 3

#if 3/BUILDOPT == 1
    <compile>
#endif
```

If BUILDOPT is not defined you get a compile error for divide by 0.  If BUILDOPT != 3 && > 0 the #if fails.

Answer (score 0):

My final implementation is to set BUILDOPT to 1 to enable the code, > 1 to disable.  Then the #if becomes #if 1/BUILDOPT==1.

Comment: This should have been an edit to the original answer, not a separate answer.