# ARMC6 ignores pre-processor directive

Tags: c++, arm, c-preprocessor

I'm compiling some C++ with ARM Compiler v6.11. As part of this code I'm conditionally including a file using pre-processor directives as below. It's nothing out of the ordinary.

```
#if BOARD == TP_EARHART_V1_0_0
    #include "LorawanTP.h"
#endif
```

My issue is that the file is being included and, as such, causing a ton of errors. I've no idea why the pre-processor directive is seemingly just being ignored.

Now, the first thing that popped into my mind was: *"Well you're obviously re-defining the BOARD macro somewhere else and it actually equals* `TP_EARHART_V1_0_0`". Unfortunately, that's not the case and I've verified that in the following way:

```
#define STRING2(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STRING2(x)
#pragma message "BOARD = " STRING(BOARD)

#if BOARD ==TP_EARHART_V1_0_0
    #include "LorawanTP.h"
#endif
```

Which yields the result:

```
[Warning] node_flow.h@23,9: BOARD = WRIGHT_V1_0_0 [-W#pragma-messages]
```

I'm not really too sure where to look now. Any insight is *greatly* appreciated.

I should note that I have also attempted, to no avail, with the following:

```
#if defined BOARD && (BOARD == TP_EARHART_V1_0_0)
```

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149189/preprocessor-equality-test-is-this-standard

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thanks for that. My question didn't state but I have indeed tried `#ifdef BOARD && (BOARD == xxx` to no avail, I shall update to reflect that.

Comment: The issue is that `TP_EARHART_V1_0_0` and `WRIGHT_V1_0_0` are probably not defined thus the preprocessor is using 0 as value in the equality test as explained in the question pointed by @formerlyknownas_463035818.

Comment: @AProgrammer But `TP_EARHART_V1_0_0` and `WRIGHT_V1_0_0` are just the possible values of `BOARD`. If `BOARD` wasn't defined then my `#pragma message...` would show that though, right? Or am I just completely misunderstanding how the pre-processor works?

Comment: `BOARD` is expand to `WRIGHT_V1_0_0` which then expand to `0`. Which is compared to the expansion of `TP_EARHART_V1_0_0 ` which is also `0`.

Comment: @AProgrammer Thank you, I understand now - please feel free to add that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest that I can come up with is something like this

Macro:

```
#define BOARD_TYPE(board) \
    ((defined( BOARD_ ## board) && (BOARD_ ## board)) ? 1 : 0)
#endif
```

Then in your code file:

```
#if BOARD_TYPE(TP_EARHART_V1_0_0)
    #include "LorawanTP.h"    
#endif
```

Then in your pre-processor or another include file set:

```
BOARD_TP_EARHART_V1_0_0 = 1
```